# Update UITabBar width on screen rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, width, uitabbar, screen-rotation

I'm creating a UITabBar programatically. Here is the code,

```
UITabBarItem *item1 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Item 1" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dashboard"] tag:1];
UITabBarItem *item2 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Item 2" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"documents"] tag:2];
UITabBarItem *item3 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Item 3" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mail"] tag:3];
UITabBarItem *item4 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Item 4" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"packages"] tag:4];

NSArray *tabbaritems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:item1, item2, item3, item4, nil];

CGRect bounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
UITabBar *tbbar = [[UITabBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 411, bounds.size.width, 49)];
[tbbar setItems:tabbaritems];
[self.view addSubview:tbbar];

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        //update UITabBar width
    }
    else {
        //update UITabBar width
    }
}
```

I have 2 questions. As you can see I have hard coded the `CGFloat y` value as 411. This looks fine in 3.5 inch screen in Portrait mode. But the problems as you can imagine are if I run it in a 4 inch device, the tab bar appears above the bottom of the screen. If I rotate the device(despite the screen size), in landscape mode the tab bar pushes down so it doesn't appear on the screen at all.

1. How can I set the position of the UITabBar dynamically so whatever
   screen it runs in whichever rotation, it always appears fixed to the
   bottom of the screen?

The other question is the width. I have set it using this line, `bounds.size.width` when the UITabBar instance gets created the first time.

1. How can I update it on screen rotation so that it expands to fill
   the whole width of the screen?

Answer (score 1):

Use two variables to stands for y-offset and width. Use a flag to swap y-offset and width in portrait and landscape. Reload the view after rotation.

And remove old tbbar from its superview in viewDidLoad.

```
...
CGRect bounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat tabbarAnchor = bounds.size.height;
CGFloat tabbarWidth = bounds.size.width;
if (_flag == 1) {
    tabbarWidth = bounds.size.height;
    tabbarAnchor = bounds.size.width;
}
UITabBar *tbbar = [[UITabBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, tabbarAnchor-69, tabbarWidth, 49)];
[tbbar setItems:tabbaritems];
[self.view addSubview:tbbar];
...

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        //update UITabBar width
        _flag = 1;
        [self viewDidLoad];
    }
    else {
        //update UITabBar width
        _flag = 0;
        [self viewDidLoad];
    }
}
```

And still suggest you to use UITabBarController which already implements rotation.

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for the response. It works great in terms of positioning the TabBar when the orientation changes. However I have come across a small issue. Say, I rotate the device to landscape mode. The TabBar positions nicely. Then when I rotate it back to portrait view, previously created TabBar in Landscape mode still appears like [this](http://i.imgur.com/NHdwY4u.png). How can I get rid of it? Thanks again. :)

Comment: I kind of have to use the `UITabBar` instead of the `UITabBarController` because I'm implementing a custom `UITabBar`.

Comment: Since every time the rotation is performed, a new subview is added to self.view, you need to clear the previously added tbbar before add new tbbar. Code could be like: `for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {  
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }`